# QGIS - problem with transparency

Tags: qgis, transparency-opacity

After making transparency of an orthophoto, I can see thin black square lines in the pdf of a layout? Anyone know if you can fix it?

[image: pdf of layout]

Comment: Please highlight "black square lines" in the image. What lines do you mean? There are a lot of black lines. Which ones are square?

Comment: If it doesn't happen when transparency isn't applied on the orthophotos, try making a temporary polygon layer with a white background and putting it just above the imagery, with transparency.

Comment: This problem has an extensive history on the ESRI forums with ArcGIS Pro where it was stated that this is an Adobe bug.  The causes may be different in that ESRI said it was related to Pro's ability to export multiple raster layers  but you might try some suggestions in it including printing to pdf or exporting as a raster and then converting that to pdf. https://community.esri.com/thread/202514-image-transparency-issue-while-exporting-to-pdf-arcgis-pro